# SvelteKit req.body undefined

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to set up SvelteKit to use it with my CMS.

I'm fetching data from my CMS in `api/query.js`, and fetching data from `api/query` in `index.svelte`.

It works great and I can get the whole data, but I get an error "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" if I include body in the fetch request. Code:

```js
// api/query.js
export async function post(req) {
  const url = API_URL;
  const auth = Buffer.from(`${API_USER_EMAIL}:${API_USER_PASSWORD}`).toString('base64');

  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Basic ${auth}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
  });
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    status: data.code,
    body: data
  }
}
```

```js
// index.svelte
export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const res = await fetch('/api/query', {
        method: 'POST',
        // body: JSON.stringify({
        //  query: 'site.title',
        // }),
    });
    const data = await res.json();

    return {
        status: data.status || 200,
        props: data
    }
}
```

The commented out portion of code is one that's causing an error. If I `console.log(req.body)` in `api/query.js` it returns `undefined`.

Is there a way I could use Express.js body-parser? Or is there any other way to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `content-type` header for both routes.

Also make sure all header keys are in lowercase.

Example:

```js
...
    headers: {
        'authorization': `Basic ${auth}`,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been trying to parse the request.body with middleware in hooks.ts and StreamReaders for an hour, but this just made it possible to use request.body and be done with it.